# Max audio sample rates?

Tags: audio, quality, sample-rate

I work as a sort of multi-purpose engineer/developer at a very small startup game company. Recently, I've been asked to help out with audio development and editing, and I've been mostly able to hold my own.

One thing I'm not very familiar with, though, is sample rates. I understand what they are, and I know that 44100 Hz is considered a sort of default because it's CD Quality.

What I want to know is if there's a sort of practical peak, where the human ear can no longer hear the difference. In graphics development, they say that the human eye can't see the difference above 60 Hz (although some people are starting to say 75-90 Hz, I think). Is there a similar limit in audio development?